# PHP Mensagem de erro Após Login

Tags: php, login

Necessito da vossa ajuda para tentar resolver um pequeno problema. 
Tenho uma página de login e após clicar ENTRAR vai para outra página `validalogin.php` validar o login.

Sempre que o utilizador falha o login o utilizador é reencaminhado para o `index.php` com o final do **URL** `index.php?login=erro2`.

Quero colocar sempre que o utilizador tiver `login=erro2` no URL eu colocar uma mensagem de erro.

```
   <?php if(header == 'erro2'){ ?>

        <div class="text-danger">
           Utilizador ou senha inválidos
         </div>        

   <?php } ?>
```

Algo assim. É possivel?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso você vai precisar trabalhar com o [`$_GET[]`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php) por exemplo:

```
   <?php if($_GET['login'] == 'erro2'){ ?>

        <div class="text-danger">
           Utilizador ou senha inválidos
         </div>        

   <?php } ?>
```

Mas aproveitando a sua pergunta existem outras forma de trabalhar com isso, por exemplo com o [`$_SESSION[]`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php) ai em vês de usar a *URL* você pode passar essa informação de forma transparente.

Por exemplo, no *redirect* de um login invalido. você define o `$_SESSION['erro']` e na pagina de `index.php` você chama esse session no lugar do `$_GET['login']` e depois limpa seu valor, vai ter o mesmo resultado, porem sem a *url* e caso o usuário de um <kbd>F5</kbd>  na pagina não irá sempre aparecer o erro.

Testa ai e veja se funciona.